# List not filling properly

Tags: python, django, list

So, i have this bit of code that is supposed to go through a list of products, link them up with their price and then display the product with the price as a 'display item' to the user on a webpage

```
for product in product_list:
    p = PricedProduct.objects.filter(proid=product)
    p.order_by('date')


    dp = DisplayProduct
    dp.proid = product.id
    dp.proname = product.productname

    print(product.productname)

    dp.proprice = p[0].value
    displaylist.insert(0,dp)
```

this is where i link up the item to the price the 'print' method is currently showing:

Apple

Banana

However when i run:

```
for dp in displaylist:
    print(dp.proname)
```

it shows:

Banana

Banana

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, as its causing my web page to just show 2 bananas instead of an apple and a banana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* initialize a `DisplayProduct`, you simply set `dp` to be a *reference* to the `DisplayProduct` class, and as a result, you change fields of the class directly:

```
for product in product_list:
    p = PricedProduct.objects.filter(proid=product)
    p.order_by('date')


    dp = DisplayProduct()  # construct a new DisplayProduct
    dp.proid = product.id
    dp.proname = product.productname

    print(product.productname)

    dp.proprice = p[0].value
    displaylist.insert(0,dp)
```

Note that this code is rather inefficient: by inserting at the top, you construct an algorithm with time complexity *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Appending at the end of the list is usually more efficient (since it has amortized cost *O(1)*). In case you need to reverse the list, it is better to reverse at the end.

I would also advice to construct a proper initializer for `DisplayProduct` (perhaps your class already has a proper initialzier), so that we can rewrite it to:

```
for product in product_list:
    p = PricedProduct.objects.filter(proid=product)
    p.order_by('date')

    # might require some changes to the __init__ of DisplayProduct
    dp = DisplayProduct(
        proid=product.id,
        proname=product.productname,
        proprice=p[0].value
    )

    print(product.productname)

    # appending is more efficient than prepending
    displaylist.append(dp)
```